# If I pushed a rod that would be so long it connected Earth to Mars and I would be strong enough to push Mars, what would happen?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics

Imagine I am here on Earth, I have a rod that connects me to Mars:[image]

I now push the rod, how long will it take before Mars is pushed by the rod?

When we do this here on Earth with sticks pushing stones it seems instantaneous. But we know speed of light is the speed limit of Universe. The distance between Earth and Mars is 20 light minutes (of course it depends on the current location because both planets orbit the Sun), so will it take 20 minutes before Mars is pushed? Or will it take even longer?

Comment: This seems like purely a physics question rather than a philosophical one, it's been addressed a few times on the physics stack exchange, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-it-possible-for-information-to-be-transmitted-faster-than-light-by-using-a-ri) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/if-i-move-a-long-solid-stick-can-i-send-message-fastest-than-light) for example. Short answer is that there are no perfectly rigid objects in relativity, if you push one end of a stick a deformation travels at the speed of sound in the material it's made of.

Comment: It's not instantaneous with a short rod on Earth either (and it has nothing to do with relativity - it's the speed of sound, not light). You push the rod and the atoms on your end move a little, and then a little bit later the atoms next to them move, and then a little bit later the atoms next to them move, and so on down the line at the speed of sound. It's a wave of displacement traveling down the rod. Imagine if you were pulling a slinky instead - the end near you moves first. It's like that, just faster (so fast as to be imperceptible) because the rod is a lot stiffer than a slinky.

Comment: @causative - "and it has nothing to do with relativity - it's the speed of sound, not light" But the speed of sound is different in different mediums (it's a function of rigidity and density), and in pre-relativistic classical physics there was no reason to expect any upper limit on possible rigidity and therefore on possible speeds of sound. Classical physics textbooks also routinely deal with idealized perfectly rigid bodies that remain rigid under acceleration, and in classical physics there is no fundamental reason such a body couldn't exist in principle.

Comment: @Hypnosifl No, wave theory and the speed of sound were understood well before relativity. Perfectly rigid objects have always been understood in classical physics as only an approximation; engineers have always needed to consider the bending of beams and such. The speed of sound in normal materials is far, far below the speed of light; the "upper limit on possible rigidity" for practical materials has nothing to do with the speed of light. It is not necessary to invoke relativity to study waves propagating through a lattice of atoms.

Comment: @causative - "No, wave theory and the speed of sound were understood well before relativity" Yes, that's exactly what I said--the notion of waves traveling at a speed of sound that was a function of rigidity and density comes from pre-relativistic classical physics. Perfectly rigid bodies were understood as an approximation for all *known* materials, but nothing in the classical theory would rule out the existence of as-yet-unknown materials of arbitrarily high rigidity (light waves were themselves imagined as sound waves in a medium called 'luminiferous ether' with extremely high rigidity).

Comment: Meanwhile, widespread acceptance of atomic theory post-dates special relativity (Einstein's 1905 paper on Brownian motion played a significant role in its increasing acceptance), and naturally it wouldn't have made sense for believers in the luminiferous ether to have imagined it as a collection of atoms held together by electromagnetic forces, since in that case there would be no ether in the spaces between atoms for the electromagnetic waves to travel through.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Even before a consensus about atoms, they were still considering sound waves through objects. Anyway, the history isn't really relevant. The point is that the delay between pushing on one end of a rod, and the other end of the rod moving, has virtually nothing to do with special relativity. It's just classical physics; the rod is effectively made up of many very stiff springs, and a compression wave propagates through them, at speeds too low for special relativity to matter. If the rod is steel the wave propagates at only 0.1% of the speed of light.

Comment: (Also, bit nitpicking, but there was "widespread" acceptance of atomic theory in classical physics through much of the 19th century; Einstein's observations on Brownian motion convinced a last few nay-sayers. Again, not really relevant to the point.)

Comment: @causative *The point is that the delay between pushing on one end of a rod, and the other end of the rod moving, has virtually nothing to do with special relativity* But the idea that this delay can't be arbitrarily tiny is a consequence of relativity. 19th century physicists who believed in luminiferous ether had no reason to rule out the idea of mediums with even higher rigidity and speed of sound.

Comment: *there was "widespread" acceptance of atomic theory in classical physics through much of the 19th century* Chemists were quicker to accept it than physicists--after Boltzmann's work deriving thermodynamic equations from statistics of hypothetical molecules, there were many who considered it plausible, but it was controversial and there were also many authorities in physics who rejected it, see https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1420513 for example

Comment: @Hypnosifl Fine. In theory, special relativity could give an upper limit to the stiffness of a material, and thus the speed of sound in that material. As long as we both understand - and the OP understands - that this is not relevant in practice for any material we have access to. (Because the speed of sound in any material we have access to isn't even 1% of the speed of light).

Comment: @causative - Yes, I agree with that. But I thought the OP might be asking about what would be possible in principle, not just what would happen with a rod made of known materials like steel, since the notion of constructing a rod stretching from Earth to Mars is already pretty fanciful by realistic standards.

Comment: If you pull the stick one meter towards you, the stick will be stretched in length one meter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest that a mechanical signal or "push" can propagate through a stick of some sort is the *speed of sound* in that stick. If we make your earth-to-mars stick out of ordinary steel, that's about ten thousand feet per second which is way, way slower than the speed of light.

Note also that for you to be able to push on Mars with a thin stick that is long enough to reach that distance requires that the stick be *infinitely stiff* so it does not "pop out" into a curved shape as soon as you start to push on it. To avoid this *columnar instability* problem would require you to make the stick no thinner than about 1/10th its length. That would render it far too heavy to be moved by human muscle power.